# java x.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Enum

Tags: java, apache, enums, jpql

I'm having trouble with this error .. I hope someone can help me here.

In my entity I have this code

```
@Id
@Column(name="TYPE_INTERFACE")
@Enumerated(value=EnumType.STRING)
@XmlElement
private TypeInterface typeInterface;
```

this my enum class:

```
@XmlEnum
public enum TypeInterface {
FF("Flat File"),
WS("Web Service"),
...
}
```

And here this a part of my query :

```
queryB.append("FROM TraductionAttribut ta WHERE ");
if (newbox.getTypeInterface() != null) {
    queryB.append(" (ta.typeInterface = :taTypeInterface OR ta.typeInterface = :taAll)");
}
...
Query q = session.createQuery(queryB.toString());
if (newbox.getTypeInterface() != null) {
    q.setParameter("taTypeInterface",newbox.getTypeInterface().name());
    q.setParameter("taAll", TypeInterface.ALL );
}
...
List<TraductionAttribut> listResult = q.list();
```

When I make q.list a get this error :

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Enum
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just omit `.name()` when setting the parameter.

```
q.setParameter("taTypeInterface",newbox.getTypeInterface());
```